# Restart the service when phone restarts in android

Tags: java, android

How can I restart my service when phone restarts?

This is what I am currently using to start the service:

```
Intent a = new Intent();
                a.setAction("com.service.Service");
                startService(a);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=9B476BA317AA36E2CB0D6517ABE60A5E?recipeId=1662) is a tutorial for this.

Comment: i put this code...restarted the emulator....but i dont see in running services...my service running

Answer (score 1):

Use a BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver and start the service from within it.

Comment: The link Harry Joy posted contains the simple code needed to do this. Essentially its three things: adding a permission to your manifest, declaring the broadcast receiver in your manifest, and adding the new broadcast receiver class (which is very short).